# Polymer paper input only in shadow dom, not visible in browser

Tags: polymer

I'm brand new to polymer (2.0), so I was just practicing with a sample application. I wanted to create a basic 'login' screen with two paper input fields.

I'll show you what I have got so far.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
        <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="./testing/login-page.html">
    </head>
    <body unresolved>
        <login-page></login-page>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my login-page.html, which is in a folder called 'testing'

```
<dom-module id="login-page">
    <template>
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
        <paper-input label="test">test</paper-input>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'login-page',
            properties: {
                prop1: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'login-page',
                },
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I have installed the paper-input using bower with the following command: `bower install paper-input`

Problem is, it's not showing up, but it is present in the shadow dom when I inspect the page. Everything in the h2 tag is showing up. Again, I'm brand new to polymer, so is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you importing the `paper-input` element in your `login-page` element?  Have you installed the 2.0 versions of the elements rather than the 1.X versions?

Comment: Following the answer below, I have installed the 2.0 version and it worked! I just have a few questions about the command, see my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Polymer 2.0 you need to download elements with `#2.0-preview` suffix.

In your case

```
bower i --save PolymerElements/paper-input#2.0-preview
```

and then import it in your page

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

Comment: That worked! A few questions about the command, what is the purpose of `i` in the command and is there a difference between --save and install?

Comment: it is shorthand for install. and `--save` means it save this command to `bower.json`. It means that somewhere in future, you are able to install all dependencies by 1 command -  `bower install ` . It is recommended to use `--save` flag. Because once you will want to share your app with others, you dont need to send whole `bower_components` folder. Only `bower.json` and your folder with elements

Comment: if it solved your problem, accept my answer by clicking on check mark. So everyone knows this question was already answered and future people will know how to solve this problem

Comment: I was going to do that, but since you answered so quickly, SO didn't let me. Should be fine now!